# Bad smell from bathroom - plumbing

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, smell

I'm living in a building of 6 floors, I'm at the 5th floor.
I made a full renovation to my apartment about 8 years.
Recently I began smelling a bad sewage smell from the bathroom (from drainage hole).

The thing I can't understand is how it's possible if I have a siphon that always keeps a high level of water such that it blocks the passageway of air...

It's driving me crazy and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Would appreciate a lot your advices,

Comment: It sounds like plumbing vents have gotten clogged , perhaps on the roof by perhaps birds nests or something similar. I'm possible to answer without much more info about the building.

Comment: Stupid question, but you have a P-trap under the sink, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The thing I can't understand is how it's possible if I have a siphon that always keeps a high level of water such that it blocks the passageway of air...**

If the building vent gets clogged, then waste falling through the common downpipe can suck water out of your U-bends/P-traps.

The solution is one of

- Get the building supervisor to fix the vents for the common downpipe(s)
- Add an **[air-admittance valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain-waste-vent_system#Internal_venting)** to the plumbing for your apartment.
- Replace your traps with **[anti-siphon traps](http://www.screwfix.com/p/mcalpine-swivel-p-trap-white-32mm/96792)**.

Also, If you leave a sink/bath/shower unused for a month, the trap can dry-out by evaporation. This is mostly solved by pouring a litre of water down the unused sink/bath/shower once every few weeks. I read that some people add a layer of oil (maybe a tiny quantity of vegetable or mineral oil) to slow down evaporation.

---

Linked examples for illustration only, seek local equivalents.